# Склейка разных типов данных

Tags: php

Нужно, чтобы по нажатию клавиши в ячейку генерировалась ссылка на википедию, где последний кусочек информации вставляется из системного имени. Почему не работает?
Неверно склеиваю данные?

```
$AddQuery = "INSERT INTO artists (wiki) VALUES 'https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/' . '$_POST[usys_name]')"; - не работает

$AddQuery = "INSERT INTO artists (wiki) VALUES 'https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/')"; - работает

$AddQuery = "INSERT INTO artists (wiki) VALUES '$_POST[usys_name]')"; - работает
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$AddQuery = "INSERT INTO artists (wiki) VALUES ('https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/" . $_POST[usys_name] . "')";